Chart.js: how to hide some text of label?
Chart.js v2.9.4
I've got some things in data -> datasets -> label but I want hide text of only one of labels at the upside.
I need something like this: Hide labels from pie chart in chartjs - but only for one label.
I tried label:"" but I still see "image" of this label.
Thank you!
At Stackoverflow.com are too many questions like this but not any with this.

I got it!
Remove label:"label name" from datasets.
"legend": {
            "display": true,
                labels: {
                    filter: function (legendItem, chartData) {
                        return (chartData.datasets[legendItem.datasetIndex].label)
                    }
                }
}

And add condition into label: label !== undefined
